# escape ticks in golang sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, go

I have the following sql code:

```
sqlStatement := `INSERT INTO listings (listing_key,lat,long)
                     VALUES(?,?,?)`
```

However, `long` is a reserved keyword in mysql so i need to `escape the column`. As in:

```
sqlStatement := `INSERT INTO listings (listing_key,lat,`long`)
                     VALUES(?,?,?)`
```

but that breaks the sql statement.

not sure how to resolve. theres a ton more columns so i need to use the multi line tick.

Comment: Can't you escape the tick with backslash?

Comment: Use “ (double quote) instead for identifiers. This is standard SQL syntax and supported in MySQL with ANSI_QUOTES. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html - issue deflected!

Answer (score 2):

Both ugly, but you can do one of:

```
statement:=`INSERT INTO listings (listing_key,lat,`+"`long`)"
```

or:

```
statement:=strings.Replace(`INSERT INTO listings (listing_key,lat,^long^)`,"^","`",-1)
```